# XAMPP is not start Apache, MySQL is working fine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I was working on my PHP project yesterday and it was working fine, but today morning after the restart XAMPP is not starting Apache for some reason. Can someone suggest how can I work around it:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:17:04 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: 1. Restart PC.
2. Try to run as administrator Or
3. Reinstall XAMPP Or
4. Or Uninstall XAMPP and Install WAMP or some similar softwares.

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown Skype or Teamviewer, if you have them installed.
They use port 80, like Apache.

Answer (score 2):

you can check which port is being used by which program using 3 methods

i) Open cmd and type netstat -b -a

ii) Use currports http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

iii)Use TCPView https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Then you can change port for that program.

If still you are unable to solve it you can uninstall the program and check.

Or you can change your apache port from 80 to 8080. but then you have to use localhost:8080. Remember to restart apache.